# Как правильно сделать ссылку в php?

Tags: php

Заранее извиняюсь за наверное нелепый и не очень грамотно поставленный вопрос,просто в пхп я полный 0.
Итак суть вопроса:
есть некая html страничка, разделенная на три части (кажется это называется tray если я не ошибаюсь), каждой из этих частей соответствует файл .php. В файле admintray.php (центральная часть html странички) вставляю ссылку,вот код:

```
print("<p><b><a href='http://ip_адрес/cgi-bin/qstat.pl'><img src='1.jpg' alt='' border='0' /><br>Череповец</a></b></p>");
```

Ссылка появляется, переход происходит, но страничка на которую осуществляется переход открывается как бы в одной части страницы с которой делался переход (в admintray вообщем),в целом же я остаюсь на странице на которой и был. Как сделать "полный" переход?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<a href="..." target="_top">...</a>`

Comment: Спасибо)Работает!

Answer (score 1):

Это называется фрейм! Каждому фрейму назначается свое имя. Страница открывается в том фрейме, имя которого указывается (как подсказал уважаемый ling) в атрибуте target. Например: имеем два фрейма:

```
<frameset>
  <frame src="menu.html" name="menu">
  <frame src="main.html" name="main">
</frameset>
```

Если ссылка находится в фрейме "menu", и содержит атрибут target="main", то при нажатии, результат будет открываться в фрейме "main".
Этот атрибут может содержать следующие служебные значения:

_blank - открывает страницу в новом окне.
_self - открывает страницу в том окне, в котором нажмут на ссылку.
_parent - открывает страницу в фрейм-родитель, если страница без фреймов то работает как _self
_top - открывает страницу поверх всех фреймов, если страница без фреймов то работает как _self